# amazon interview prob

Tags: algorithm

There is a big file of words which is dynamically changing. We are continuously adding some words into it. How would you keep track of top 10 trending words at each moment?

I found this question in a blog but I couldn't understand the answer. 
The answer is: hash table + min-heap

I understand why hashtable but not min-heap part, can someone help me?

Comment: You usually want a min-heap to keep track of the highest N answers, because at each stage you have a candidate answer and you want to know if it is better than the worst answer in the min-heap - if it is, remove the worst answer of the top N from the min-heap and insert the candidate. Having the - intuitive - max-heap makes it very easy to pick out the very best answer, but when deciding whether to accept a new candidate answer, this is not what you want. (Just remember that when you extract the top N answers at the end, they will come off with the worst of those N first).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's `top 10 trending words` then you should use a `max-heap` along with a `hash-table`.

When a new word is added to the file then:

- `Create` a new element `x` with `x.key=word` and `x.count=1`.
- `Add` `x` to the `hash-table`. `O(1)`.
- `Add` `x` to the `max-heap`. `O(lgn)`.

When an existing word is added to the file then:

- `Find` `x` in the `hash-table`. `O(1)`.
- `Update` `x.count` to `x.count++`.

When there is a need to retrieve the `top 10 trending words` then:

- `Extract` 10 times from the `max-heap`. `10*O(lgn)=O(10*lgn)=O(lgn)`.

As you can see, all the needed operations are done in at most `O(lgn)`.

Comment: you would want to use a min heap: when an existing word that's not in top 10 becomes a top 10, removing the min would be consistent time.

Comment: "Update x.count to x.count++ in the max-heap" - shouldn't that be `O(n)`? You have to first find `x` in the `max-heap`, but you don't know where it is. Once you find it, incrementing it and bubbling it up is a `O(lgn)` operation.

Comment: @B-Con: Since `max-heap` and `hash-table` point to the same element `x` then there is no need to find it again in the hash table. I will fix that, thanks.

Comment: You have to use a MinHeap, not MaxHeap. So, if you have k items in the heap, the peek of the heap is the smallest; and everyone else (k - 1) is larger than the peek. Now, if a new word with count > peek comes in, we want to extract the min (O(logk)) and insert the new item (O(logk)).If new item has count smaller than peek, that means it is smaller than any other item in the heap (as it's a Min Heap). We just discard that word as that will not be a part of top k.

Comment: @Amit: You are right. Why not add your solution as another one?

Comment: The answer is correct, except that it should use a MinHeap. Top 10 trending words would have counts like 1000, 900, 800, ... 100.  So from these values you'd want to keep track of the minimum value.  Once another word hits a greater count (i.e. 110) than the minimum (100 in the above example) you pop from the minHeap (i.e. in the example case, the word with 100 count) and insert the new word (with 110 count in the given example).  Using a max heap will not allow you to see when to replace add a new value (that is, you don't know the smallest count within the top 10).

Comment: I believe we should be using Max-Heap. Lets say when I start reading file  bunch of 10 words are repeated and then word "X" is repeated for the rest of file. If I use min heap, word x will never make into the heap. If the whole file is pre-processed then Min heap is correct. If we are reading from a stream then it should be max heap.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to keep the top 10, using a max-heap is overkill. Keeping the 10 entries in a sorted array will be simpler and faster.

For sorting, just use insertion sort starting from the bottom of the array. You will have to check for the case where the candidate is already on the top ten updating its position if required.

Comment: if you don't keep the other entries, no new entry will ever make it to the top 10.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: obviously you still need the hash table to count the hits per entry. My point is that using a min-heap for managing the top 10 entries is overkill. A simple sorted array would perform better and the implementation would be also quite simpler. Actually, for an incrementally updated top-N (and unless you have massive ties) a sorted array would always perform better than a min-heap.